# Error when try to take data from Android Database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I create a Database in Android with SQLite. I create a little class that extract some datas from my DB. This is my class code:

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class GetDataDb {

    public String [] getAmb(SQLiteDatabase db){
        //"SELECT NOME_AMB FROM T_DIZ_AMB";
        String [] colonne = {"NOME_AMB"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query("T_DIZ_AMB", colonne, null, null, null, null, null);
        int numero_righe=cursor.getCount();

        //inizializzo le variabili necessarie. Con un ciclo for creo un array
        //di stringhe con i nomi degli ambulatori
        int k;
        String [] ambulatorio;
        ambulatorio = new String[numero_righe];
        for(k=0;k<numero_righe+1;k++){
            ambulatorio[k]=cursor.getString(k);
        }
        return ambulatorio;
    }
}
```

my Database code is :

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class LoginDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME="Login_DB";
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1;

    public LoginDataBase(Context context){
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override 
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
        String sql="";
        sql+= "CREATE TABLE T_LOGIN (";
        sql+= " _id_LOGIN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql+= " USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql+= " PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL";
        sql+=")";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        String sql2="";
        sql2+= "CREATE TABLE T_PROFILO (";
        sql2+= " _id_PROFILO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql2+= " NOME TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " COGNOME TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " ETA TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " SESSO TEXT(1) NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " CODICE_FISCALE TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " CITTA TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " INDIRIZZO TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " TELEFONO TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " _id_L INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL,";
        sql2+= " FOREIGN KEY(_id_L) REFERENCES T_LOGIN(_id_LOGIN)";
        sql2+= ")";
        db.execSQL(sql2);

        String sql3="";
        sql3+= "CREATE TABLE T_DIZ_AMB (";
        sql3+= " _id_AMB INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql3+= " NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql3+= ")";
        db.execSQL(sql3);

        String sql4="";
        sql4+= "CREATE TABLE T_DIZ_PRE (";
        sql4+= " _id_PRE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql4+= " NOME_PRE TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql4+= " _id_FK_AMB INTEGER NOT NULL,";
        sql4+= " FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_AMB) REFERENCES T_DIZ_AMB(_id_AMB)";
        sql4+= ")";
        db.execSQL(sql4);

        String sql5="";
        sql5+="CREATE TABLE T_RIEPILOGO (";
        sql5+=" _id_RIEPILOGO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql5+= " DATA DATE NOT NULL,";
        sql5+= " ORA TIME NOT NULL,";
        sql5+= " _id_FK_L2 INTEGER NOT NULL,";
        sql5+= " FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_L2) REFERENCES T_LOGIN(_id_LOGIN),";
        sql5+= " _id_FK_PRE INTEGER NOT NULL,";
        sql5+= " FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_PRE) REFERENCES T_DIZ_PRE(_id_PRE)";
        sql5+= ")";
        db.execSQL(sql5);

        //INSERT di dati
        String sql6="";
        sql6+= "INSERT INTO T_DIZ_AMB (_id_AMB,NOME_AMB)";
        sql6+= "VALUES (1,'Cardiologia')";
        db.execSQL(sql6);
     } 

     @Override 
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
        // Aggiornamento delle tabelle 
     } 
}
```

Eclipse say that I haven't created T_DIZ_AMB table. But watching my Database Code I say that I have created it. This is my logcat:

```
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): Process: com.example.prenotazione_esame, PID: 1109
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prenotazione_esame/com.example.prenotazione_esame.Prenota}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: T_DIZ_AMB (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT NOME_AMB FROM T_DIZ_AMB
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: T_DIZ_AMB (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT NOME_AMB FROM T_DIZ_AMB
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.GetDataDb.getAmb(GetDataDb.java:11)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.Prenota.onCreate(Prenota.java:25)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-15 05:00:31.567: E/AndroidRuntime(1109):     ... 11 more
05-15 05:00:34.737: I/Process(1109): Sending signal. PID: 1109 SIG: 9
```

How Can I resolve this error? Thank you.

RE-EDIT:
I remove the comma, but now I have this error:

```
05-15 04:59:49.777: D/dalvikvm(1083): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-15 04:59:55.067: D/(1083): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb744aab8, tid 1083
05-15 04:59:55.217: W/EGL_emulation(1083): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 04:59:55.247: D/OpenGLRenderer(1083): Enabling debug mode 0
05-15 05:00:14.357: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1083): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
05-15 05:00:14.357: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1083):   in android.widget.EditText{b2d8b5b8 VFED..CL .F...... 173,85-320,110 #7f05003c app:id/Password02}
05-15 05:00:14.357: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1083):   0: sent at 3422921000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=3422921, downTime=3422776, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
05-15 05:00:17.857: D/(1109): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7349238, tid 1109
05-15 05:00:18.057: W/EGL_emulation(1109): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 05:00:18.127: D/OpenGLRenderer(1109): Enabling debug mode 0
05-15 05:00:20.977: D/dalvikvm(1109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 5% free 2927K/3072K, paused 67ms, total 81ms
05-15 05:00:22.757: W/EGL_emulation(1109): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 05:00:22.867: I/Choreographer(1109): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-15 05:00:29.057: W/EGL_emulation(1109): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 05:00:31.227: D/dalvikvm(1109): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 5% free 3357K/3524K, paused 88ms, total 89ms
05-15 05:00:31.517: E/SQLiteLog(1109): (1) no such table: T_DIZ_AMB
05-15 05:00:31.527: D/AndroidRuntime(1109): Shutting down VM
```

This is my Prenota.java. As you can see this file call the class GetDataDb.

```
package com.example.prenotazione_esame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class Prenota extends Activity {
    private LoginDataBase dbLogin;
    GetDataDb dbData = new GetDataDb();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prenota);
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAmbulatorio);
        dbLogin = new LoginDataBase(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbLogin.getWritableDatabase();
        String [] array = dbData.getAmb(db);      
        //String [] array = {"a","b"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,R.layout.row,R.id.textViewList,array
                );
        lista.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        //arrayAdapter.add("A");
    }
}
```

This is my new logcat with the problem in the foreign key:

```
05-15 07:16:14.845: E/SQLiteLog(1493): (1) near "_id_FK_PRE": syntax error
05-15 07:16:14.855: D/AndroidRuntime(1493): Shutting down VM
05-15 07:16:14.855: W/dalvikvm(1493): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a5dba8)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): Process: com.example.prenotazione_esame, PID: 1493
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "_id_FK_PRE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE T_RIEPILOGO ( _id_RIEPILOGO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DATA DATE NOT NULL, ORA TIME NOT NULL, _id_FK_L2 INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_L2) REFERENCES T_LOGIN(_id_LOGIN), _id_FK_PRE INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_PRE) REFERENCES T_DIZ_PRE(_id_PRE))
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginDataBase.onCreate(LoginDataBase.java:70)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity.executeLogin(LoginActivity.java:54)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity.access$1(LoginActivity.java:45)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:36)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 07:16:14.895: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 07:16:17.375: I/Process(1493): Sending signal. PID: 1493 SIG: 9
```

new logcat after resolve foreign key:

```
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): Process: com.example.prenotazione_esame, PID: 1592
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prenotazione_esame/com.example.prenotazione_esame.Prenota}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.GetDataDb.getAmb(GetDataDb.java:21)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.example.prenotazione_esame.Prenota.onCreate(Prenota.java:26)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-15 07:31:38.235: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: String sql3="";
        sql3+= "CREATE TABLE T_DIZ_AMB (";
        sql3+= " _id_AMB INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql3+= " NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql3+= ")";

remove last ","

Comment: make sure your Database class and your activity are both different thing.

Comment: I remove the comma but now I have new error. I post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is my new logcat with the problem in the foreign key:

Move the `FOREIGN KEY` declarations at the end. You cannot have column definitions like `_id_FK_PRE INTEGER NOT NULL` after a table constraint like `FOREIGN KEY`, as described in the [syntax diagram](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

[image]

---

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: The condition here is wrong:

```
ambulatorio = new String[numero_righe];
for(k=0;k<numero_righe+1;k++){
    ambulatorio[k]=cursor.getString(k);
}
```

Change to `k<numero_righe` e.g. remove the `+1`.

Change `getString(k)` to `getString(0)` since there's only one column value in the cursor.

Also consider moving the cursor to a new row with `moveToNext()` unless you want the same value over and over again.

Comment: now my Database run well, but there is another problem. I post another new logcat.

Comment: Uh. This is getting out of hand. Please try to have only one problem per each question. SO is not your interactive debugging service. Answered your next problem, for now.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Now my app run well. Thank you again. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra `,` in the line

```
sql3+= " NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL,";
```

and try again.

Answer (score 2):

Your  query is wrong

```
 String sql3="";
        sql3+= "CREATE TABLE T_DIZ_AMB (";
        sql3+= " _id_AMB INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql3+= " NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL,"; //comma should not be here
        sql3+= ")";
```

Remove the comma **","** from the last field and change it as below;

```
String sql3="";
        sql3+= "CREATE TABLE T_DIZ_AMB (";
        sql3+= " _id_AMB INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql3+= " NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL";
        sql3+= ")";
```

**EDITED:**

Define all your `FORIENG KEY` at the last in your table that is the rule. 
Change your query as below:

```
    sql5+= " _id_FK_L2 INTEGER NOT NULL,";
    sql5+= " _id_FK_PRE INTEGER NOT NULL,";
    sql5+= " FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_L2) REFERENCES T_LOGIN(_id_LOGIN),";
    sql5+= " FOREIGN KEY(_id_FK_PRE) REFERENCES T_DIZ_PRE(_id_PRE)";
    sql5+= ")";
```

Comment: @Gianluca From your error `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` It shows that you are doing some time consuming task on main UI thread. Post some more code.

Comment: I add more code. Another file Java. Maybe the error is inside this class.

Comment: @Gianluca Are you handling any kind of key events in your code ?

Comment: @GrlsHu sorry I'm very new to Android and java. What's mean?

Comment: @Gianluca I mean are you handling any type of keyboard events in your code anywhere? Is that your whole file code of `Prenota`?

Comment: @Gianluca Once try to clean your project any run again. Also initialize your `GetDataDb` instance inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: I try to clean my project! Prenota is called by clicking on a push button. Tis button is in another java file, called main.java.

Comment: Have you created instance of `GetDataDb` inside `onCreate()` ? @Gianluca

Comment: The problem is the same. Table T_DIZ_AMB is not found. I can't understund why.

Comment: @Gianluca Have you removed comma as i said from your create table query of  `T_DIZ_AMB` ?

Comment: Yes I removed the comma from T_DIZ_AMB

Comment: @Gianluca Try to change your select query as `Cursor cursor = db.query("T_DIZ_AMB", null, null, null, null, null, null);`. Do not specify column name.

Comment: I have the same error. T_DIZ_AMB not exist. why this happened?

Comment: Just try to uninstall the app once and install the fresh new app and check. @Gianluca

Comment: May be its because you might be running your old app so it won't have reflected the new changes of database.

Comment: I unistal and reinstall my app. Now ALL app don't run but the problem is different. My logcat says that there is a problem in my LoginDataBase.java when I definied my foreign key _id_FK_PRE. What do you think about it?

Comment: why I have to change it? My table T_PROFILO run well. There is some problem in this code line?

Comment: Then why are you saying there is problem in foreign key?

Comment: yes, my logcat say that there is a problem in the foreign key _id_FK_PRE, this foreign key is in the sql code that create table T_RIEPILOGO. (sql5 string).

Comment: Post your logcat in your question. @Gianluca

Comment: I post my newlogcat in the question. can you see something strange in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Remove last comma(,) (`NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL,`) in this `SQL` statement:

```
String sql3="";
        sql3+= "CREATE TABLE T_DIZ_AMB (";
        sql3+= " _id_AMB INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,";
        sql3+= " NOME_AMB TEXT NOT NULL,";
        sql3+= ")";
        db.execSQL(sql3);
```

Check your logs while executing this query, you will get exception while executing this line...